# What's a good web-based inventory management system?

Tags: webapp-rec

What's a good web-based inventory management system for stock tracking? It should be able to do inventory level tracking as well.

Comment: I have been looking for one for a couple years and I have not found anything decent. I have given up searching and started to write my own. I have started to build it but I still have a long way to go. I hope to have a version 1.0 around this time next year.

Comment: this is more a comment than an answer.  If you are going to release your own version (either open source or commercial) perhaps you could add a link??

Comment: -1 Seconding @christian's thoughts. Anecdotal commentary as an answer is typically frowned upon unless there is some significant insight the asker might gather from it to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've been searching for years and finally came across a new web-based inventory management system that recently launched, called [SalesBinder](http://www.salesbinder.com). It's fairly limited but I really like it for my purposes.

I'd recommend having a look at that if you haven't settled yet. It's also free if you don't need a lot of space.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Personally, I am running a small wholesale business + online commerce, where I am selling health care related products and sale on different places in Asia and selling my products on Amazon, eBay, I am using https://www.emergeapp.net/ multichannel inventory management software, till date I am satisfied with their services. Recommended!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need you might find [D4H](http://www.decisionsforheroes.com/) suitable. It it used by rescue teams for many things including managing their equipment stash and the equipment module is being actively worked on to improve the management.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what technology your looking at wanting to use or if this would even fit the bill but you could check out the [iTracker - .Net Inventory Tracker Starter Kit](http://itracker.codeplex.com/). It's open source, and usable.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't looking for one that is free, check out http://www.visualonline.net/Default.htm.

Answer (score 0):

We're using a generic database interface called [WebDB](http://github.com/samwilson/kohana_webdb) (that I wrote) to track assets and stock.  Doesn't do anything particularly inventory-specific, but if you're comfortable with MySQL, and relying on SQL views (etc.) for reporting functionality, then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's been a while since this question, I thought I'd let you know about the PHP Inventory System. An online demo as well as fully functional 30 days trial is available at www.the-business-manager.com

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

[Ordoro](http://www.ordoro.com) may be a good fit for your needs. It tracks inventory across multiple locations and is a 100% web-based system.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://www.peoplevox.co.uk). They have a web based inventory management system that can utilise mobile computers for barcode scanning. It can integrate with accounting  systems, ERP's and website back-ends.

The software is integration-ready for Magento, OSCommerce and Sage. It has open API's, which make integration into most up to date software relatively easy.